# How to create duplicate connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer, there is no command to create a connection based on an existing connection, and just change some of the connection attributes, like the username and password. Edit->Copy is disabled. So how can this be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Click the green + button in the Connections tab.
2. Select the connection to duplicate
3. Simply edit the name of the connection. If you follow the steps below, this will not rename the connection, but will create a new one.
4. Edit the other connection parameters as required.
5. Click Test, and check for a Success message subtly hidden near the bottom left corner of the dialog box.
6. Click Connect

Your new connection will now be connected. It's not very intuitive, but it works.